# How to notify the whole application the language switch?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

i am using ngx-translate for my angular application.
i created a seperate component called `lang-switch.component.ts` for making language switching.

```
    public onChange(langSelectedCode: string) {
    this.translate.use(langSelectedCode);
    }
```

my doubt is how can i detect this change in all my rest of the components and lazy-loaded modules ?

https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example

i refered this stackblitz example which is very simple and has only one component and it did not help.

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is. Your stackblitz works as expected.

Comment: Use a `BehaviorSubject` to emit language change. Subscribe to that in `AppComponent`

Comment: it works for single component ...but i have like 10 other modules and other components where i want to detect the language change

Comment: i guess using BehaviourSubject in each of the modules is a wrong approach

Comment: Why is it wrong? It totally serves the purpose of app wide notification.

Comment: you're right ...but i guess there must be much cleaner approach specifically for achieving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right implementation is to use Shared modules 
https://medium.com/@lopesgon/translate-angular-4-with-ngx-translate-and-multiple-modules-7d9f0252f139

Comment: How to share between components not modules ?